# Swift textfield rightview custom UIButton image size issue (Secure field toggle)

Tags: swift, image, uibutton, uitextfield, textfield

I have a custom button which works as a secure text toggle button - the image size is fine on larger iPhones, but on smaller Iphone8, iPhone 7 etc. The image is too big, see below.

I have tried adding constraints and modifying the CGrect of the button but this strangely has no effect on the size of the image.

I have tried a smaller image size but the image is just too small. Do I need different images for different device sizes or is there a way around this in code ?

Thanks

[image: Iphone7plus Screenshot]

[image: Iphone8 Screenshot]

```
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    //let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: self.frame.height))
    setPasswordToggleImage(button)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    
    // Debug
    //button.backgroundColor = .blue
    //button.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(self.frame.size.width - 25), y: CGFloat(5), width: CGFloat(25), height: CGFloat(25))
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.togglePasswordView), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.rightView = button
    self.rightViewMode = .always
    button.alpha = 0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating correct assets for x1 x2 and x3 fixed the issue.